# Xamarin async task initiation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, task

Here i have two different approaches to define and call async task method
1.

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace foo{
    public class bar{
        public bar(){
            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData(){
            var data=await getData<List<string>>("http://foobar.com/city");
        }

        private Task<T> getData<T>(string url){
            return Task.Run(async()=>{
                try{
                    var client=new HttpClient();
                    var response=await client.GetAsync(url);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    using(var reader=new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())){
                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                        return data;
                    }
                }catch(Exception){}

                return default(T);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

2.

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace foo{
    public class bar{
        public bar(){
            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData(){
            var data=await getData<List<string>>("http://foobar.com/city");
        }

        private async Task<T> getData<T>(string url){
            try{
                var client=new HttpClient();
                var response=await client.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                using(var reader=new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())){
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
                    return data;
                }
            }catch(Exception){}

            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

difference of these in `getData` method. 1 just using `Task` and 2. using `async Task`.
both of these run normally as expected, but which is the right or best approaches to use? 
and please give some explanation

Comment: There is little practical difference. For a description of what differences do exist, see marked duplicate. Note that in your #1 example, you are doing little more than executing the same `async` method found in #2, except wrapped in a `Task`. You could have just called the `async` lambda delegate directly and returned the result.

Answer (score 0):

In method 1 you are explicitly creating a `Task`, with all the overhead of running it, and using it to await other tasks.

Method 2 is the way to go as you aren't creating the unnecessary overhead of the extra `Task`.

Additionally, unless you know exactly what you are doing, **do not** use `async void` - [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)